# How to include search directory into FOR-DO loop while using "delims=" for a list of extensions

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, file-extension

In Windows 10, via batch, I want to include the directory which a list of file extensions are to be searched; and process those files with those specific extensions in that folder.

I have a batch file and I drag&drop a folder onto it (or its shorcut) to invoke the batch.
Thus the folder path is passed to the batch file as %1 argument/parameter.
My need is NOT related with passing files or etc.; more than one folders; whether or not there are subdirs in that folder... as parameter(s).

The portion of the batch which I need help is as follows:

```
PUSHD %1
REM or by CD %1
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *.tif *.jpg 2^>NUL') DO (
REM or by, though unwanted: FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B %1\*.tif %1\*.jpg 2^>NUL') DO (
REM  CALL :DOSOMETHING "with %~dpnx1\%%I and other arguments"
)
```

As it is seen in the code, I'm able to *Do Something on/process* files successfully with TIF and JPG extensions in folder %1 by either using `PUSHD` that directory or `CD` to that directory. Or by omitting PUSHD and CD; and adding/changing `%1\*.TIF` etc. in front of delimeters in the list. All are ok. But I would like to use an elegant approach to perform this. But not via a list of `%1\*.EXTENSION` from a lookup file. **Rather, including %1 into FOR line somewhere between `FOR` and `(` (opening paranthesis).** Is it possible? If so, how please? I did read some RTFM but fail to comprehend if there are any help for this. I also made some combinations of try&error but to no avail.

You may well say there is no need to use `"%~dpnx1\%%I"` and using only `"%%I"`, since PUSHD/CD is used, will do the same thing all along in the batch file, but I want to get rid of PUSHD/CD if possible.

Another point, if it is appropriate to ask a non-relevant question...
Although I did not use `usebackq` option inside `"delims="`, and/or I did not use %1 in surrounding double quotes (`%1` only, not as `"%1"`), the code is able to be executed successfully for both directories & file names with spaces. May I ask why?

Comment: Personally I think this is a poor coding choice. By using the dir command with the passed directory argument, the FOR command is not aware of the directory it got the file from which forces you to use %1 every time you need to reference that file if you do not use pushd first.

Comment: "_... the FOR command is not aware of the directory it got the file from..._"
This is exactly what I dislike in my code. I failed to express it in the manner you did. Yes, @Squashman , you are exactly right. I want to enhance that portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What about using something other than the `Dir` command? For example `Robocopy`:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe %1 NULL
 *.tif *.jpg
 /L /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS 2^>NUL'
) Do Call :DOSOMETHING "with %%G and other arguments"
```

Please note, whilst this is technically a one line command, I have split it into a fully valid but more readable and easiliy modified layout. Simply replace your list of extension globs on the second line, or add to them as necessary.

I have used the `%1` variable to represent your dragged and dropped directory. Whilst `"%~1"` would arguably be more robust generally, it should not be needed for your specific situation, because the GUI drag and drop will automatically doublequote the directory if needed.

Comment: "_What about using something other than the Dir command? For example Robocopy_"
What can I say @Compo ? Lovely! Using Robocopy would never occur to me. Thank you. When I previously made "using a list of files in a batch-file" or "using files with specific extensions in a batch-file" kind of searches, all I found was using `dir /A-D /B` . Though my need was a command which is able to define "the directory to look for files" AND "the files with specific extensions" separately. I will try your offer and I think this will solve my issue. I will post soon.